# compact framework windows CE using ExtEscape to control the brightness

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

I need to be able to control brightness of my Windows CE 5.0 device.

I've found that there is an API function ExtEscape to do that ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453063 ) but it needs a structure ContrastCmdInputParm (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa447689 ) as a parameter.
Since ExtEscape is unmanaged, I cannot pass a .net structure.

What is the simplest way to call this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you go down this road, contact your OEM to see if they have an API for controlling backlight intensity.  In my experience *no one* implements it via ExtEscape (I've not seen it even once).  Generally if backlight adjustment is supported at all (sometimes it's not physiclaly possible on a device, sometimes it's not implemented by the OEM), then it has a proprietary API for adjusting it.

So again, contact your device OEM before going any further to avoid wasting your own time.

Comment: My OEM provides a dll library to change the brightness, but I thought that it would be better to use something build in. If the ExtEscape function doesn't work with brightness in most devices, it doesn't make sense to use it.

Comment: I did some tests using brightness library from my OEM. When I change the brightness using this library everything works fine except that when system goes to one of the idle modes and then wake up, the brightness is overridden by a default value. Any idea how to workaround it? I need to be able to set the brightness pernamently.

Comment: Either ask your OEM to fix the library bugs/features that you are using or create an application that changes the brightness to your desired level in each system power state change.